How to implement grpc api calls with python
I have the below grpc request which is working fine with Postman:-
URL :- 10.91.151.107:30105
Payload :- {
    "headend": { "v4": 173768306 },
    "tailend": { "v4": 173768309 },
    "dataplane": "DATAPLANE_MPLS",
    "o_metric": "METRIC_TYPE_IGP",
    "constraints": { "unprotected_segments": true ,"max_segments":10 ,"return_path_max_segments":10 },
    "corouted_return_path": true
}

There is no proto buf imported for the above request. I can using it is using the server reflection to get "Unary" as "StatelessCalc/SinglePath"

How can I invoke the same request with python from pycharm?
from grpc_requests import Client

client = Client.get_by_endpoint("localhost:50051")
assert client.service_names == ["helloworld.Greeter"]

request_data = {"name": "sinsky"} 
say_hello_response = client.request("helloworld.Greeter", "SayHello", request_data)
assert say_hello_response ==  {"message":"Hello sinsky!"}


The following code should replicate the method call:
from grpc_requests import Client

endpoint = "10.91.151.107:30105"
service = "srs.te_calc.v1.StatelessCalc"
method = "SinglePath",

client = Client.get_by_endpoint(
    endpoint,
    ssl=False,
)

assert set(client.service_names) == set([
    "grpc.health.v1.Health",
    "grpc.reflection.v1.ServerReflection",
    service,
]), "Failed"

rqst = {
    "headend": {
        "v4": 173768306
    },
    "tailend": {
        "v4": 173768309
    },
    "dataplane": "DATAPLANE_MPLS",
    "o_metric": "METRIC_TYPE_IGP",
    "constraints": {
        "unprotected_segments": true,
        "max_segments": 10,
        "return_path_max_segments": 10
    },
    "corouted_return_path": true
}
resp = client.request(
    service,
    method,
    rqst,
)
print(resp)


I have tried the same , but it didn't work as expected. It is giving the follwoing error :
File "C:\pythonProject1\test_blacklist\sra_grpc_requests.py", line 7, in 
client = Client.get_by_endpoint(endpoint,ssl=False)
File "C:\pythonProject1\venv\Lib\site-packages\grpc_requests\client.py", line 139, in get_by_endpoint
_cached_clients[endpoint] = cls(endpoint, **kwargs)
File "C:\pythonProject1\venv\Lib\site-packages\grpc_requests\client.py", line 505, in init
self.register_all_service()

File "C:\pythonProject1\venv\Lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\json_format.py", line 570, in _ConvertFieldValuePair
raise ParseError(
google.protobuf.json_format.ParseError: Message type "srs.te_calc.v1.SinglePathRequest" has no field named "backend" at "SinglePathRequest".
Available Fields(except extensions): "['headend', 'tailend', 'dataplane', 'oMetric', 'constraints', 'coroutedReturnPath']"
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Oh my mistake, update answer with r/backend/tailend

You're welcome! I'm pleased to hear that it helped.
